# What is the timeframe for Mastercard's "zero-liability" policy?

Tags: liability, terms-of-service, consumer-protection, credit-card

Other types of transaction disputes such as "product not received" has a clear reporting timeframe of 120 days or 540 days. That is, the consumer is usually protected only if the report is made within 120 days for most cases.

I've checked the terms and conditions from [Mastercard official website](https://www.mastercard.com/global/en/personal/get-support/zero-liability-terms-conditions.html); however, no time limited is detailed there.

I wonder if there is a **detailed Mastercard zero liability policy t&c** preferably with details about the timeframe of "zero-liability policy".

Answer (score 2):

Only Mastercard can answer with any degree of certainty what their policy is any why they haven't advertised the time limits, but [this article by Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-credit-mastercard-debit-idUSKBN0EF1CB20140604) summaries the US Federal law at [12 CFR § 1005.6 - Liability of consumer for unauthorized transfers](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/12/1005.6) by saying...

> ...if you report the loss within two days, federal law caps consumer responsibility at $50. If you report it within 60 days of receiving a statement that shows the fraudulent transactions, liability is capped at $500. If you don’t report it within 60 days, that liability is unlimited.

And they comment that...

> ...Most credit card issuers, however, **set the cap at zero.**

(I haven't repoduced the legislations's text as the quotes from the Reuters' article does a good job of summarising it, although at the expense of some detail and precision.)

Comment: I thought about calling MasterCard by myself but as a to B company they seem not have a line directly dealing with individual customers.